# My PC won't wake up from sleep until I long-press the shutdown button?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, sleep

Like I wrote in the title. My PC suddenly won't wake up from sleep using normal methods anymore. Usually, I just press 1 key on keyboard or press a button on my mouse and it turns right back on like a happy puppy.

But after it crashed last night due to me uninstalling a software (LDplayer) and the uninstaller freezing up and crashing the system, now my PC won't wake up from sleep unless I long-press the shutdown button, which should, of course, shut it down.

Here's a video showing my problem, maybe you guys can figure it out? thank you.

[Youtube Video](https://youtu.be/-aktd3ilCrk)

Answer (score 1):

> it crashed last night due to me uninstalling a software (LDplayer) and
> the uninstaller freezing up and crashing the system, now my PC won't
> wake up from sleep unless I long-press the shutdown button, which
> should, of course, shut it down.

It is hard to say what operating system damage was done in the above, but start with a Windows 10 Repair Install and use the option to Keep Everything.

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Start with the option to Keep Everything.

This process should update and fix drivers, but you may also wish to look for and install an updated Power Driver from the manufacturer's support site.